# How can I know if there are errors when loading an iframe with srcdoc?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe to which I pass html, css and js content with the srcdoc property and now I would like to log all errors such as syntax etc. I don't need to know if it's syntax or not, I just know if it's error or warning.

I've tried redefining the console.log, console.warn and console.error functions and it works when called explicitly, but not if it's a problem with javascript.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Iframes</title>
  <script>
    // Define the error handler function
    function handleIframeError(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
      // Log the error information
      console.error('Iframe Error:', message, source, lineno, colno, error);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe defer
        title="testFrame"
        srcdoc="
        <script>console.log('Hello world!');</script>
        <p>Hello world!</p>">
    </iframe>

  <script>
    // Attach the error handler to the window.onerror event
    window.onerror = handleIframeError;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It tried using your code and I could only see 'Hello world!' instead of 'Iframe error: ...'

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the iframe's window using `document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow`.

```html
<iframe srcdoc="<script>unassignedFunc()</script>"></iframe>

<script>
    // Get the iframe's window then attach an error handler to the iframe's onerror event
    document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow.onerror = function(message) {
        // Display error message
        alert(message);
    }
</script>
```

You can also do a check for other console methods like `console.log`:

```html
<iframe srcdoc='<script>console.log("I am from the iframe");</script>'></iframe>

<script>
    // Get the iframe's window then manipulate the iframe's console.log
    document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow.console.log = function() {
        // Display all recurring console.log()
        alert(Array.from(arguments));
    }
</script>
```